# Quand utiliser « passage » et « passation » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

J'ai du mal à faire la distinction entre ces deux termes.

On parle par exemple de [passation des pouvoirs](http://www.gouvernement.fr/passation-des-pouvoirs-entre-francois-hollande-et-emmanuel-macron) :

> La cérémonie de **passation des pouvoirs** entre le Président de la
>   République, François Hollande, et son successeur, Emmanuel Macron se
>   déroule ce dimanche 14 mai 2017.

J'ai l'impression que les deux mots ont le même sens, mais que *passation* entraîne implicitement des formalités (contrat).

Quand et pourquoi doit-on utiliser l'un ou l'autre ?
<sup>Par exemple, parle-t-on du *passage d'une commande*, ou de la *passation d'une commande* ?</sup>

Dans la mesure du possible, je veux bien plusieurs exemples de l'usage de chacun des mots.

Answer (score 3):

Ces mots sont tous les deux dérivés du verbe *passer*.

Le mot *passage* est bien plus ancien (1100) et, tout comme *passer*, peut être utilisé dans de nombreux contextes. [CNRTL : passage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passage)

L'usage du terme *passation* n'est attesté que quelques 400 ans plus tard et revêt un caractère juridique. [CNRTL : passation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passation)

Ainsi donc, on dit bien "passation de pouvoir". En revanche, on parlera plutôt de "passage de relais". Pour une commande, on utiliserait donc *passation* (comme indiqué sur la page du 2nd lien).

Comment: Merci pour l’étymologie, mais je reste un peu sur ma faim : Comment savoir quand utiliser l'un ou l'autre ? Est-ce que tu as quelques exemples concrets ? Merci :)

Comment: @Mistalis Comme tu peux le voir dans les liens que j'ai donné, les cas d'utilisation de *passation* sont plus restreints et liés à des domaines spécifiques. Si ce que tu veux dire ne correspond pas à ces cas, utilise donc *passage*. Au passage(hehe), le mot *passage* est tellement plus souvent utilisé que tu ne risque pas grand chose à l'employer par défaut. Même si l'expression correcte est "passation de commande", peu de gens relèverait la faute dans un contexte informel.